# Validate using model rules before saving in Yii

Tags: yii

I am building a CSV import, and am looking to run through the CSV and display any potential errors to the user before actually doing the import.

$model->getErrors() only works after an attempted $model->save(), I am looking to get those potential errors before the save so the importer can then adjust his CSV file and make the necessary changes to have a flawless import.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is when using CActiveRecord

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$model->validate();
$model->getErrors();

Answer (score 0):

at first place, why dont you try this tool wrote by me: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/401/simple-csv-export/

Comment: Thank you, but if you read my question, I'm discussing import only.